# Android Studio & git - getting a file from a specific tag

Tags: android, eclipse, git, android-studio

We have recently migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio and I'm facing a troublesome issue to view a file from a specific tag.

Let me explain:

Each time we release a version we tag it with a version name: `git tag -a v1.1.105 -m "releasing version 105"`. Afterwards, when we might receive a crash from that specific version in a certain line. I must view the file that was packaged in v1.1.105 in order to find the erroneous line of code.

In Eclipse, I could just right click the file -> Team -> Show in History -> double click the tag from the history view and viola! I get the code from that specific version.

Does anybody know how to do the same on Android Studio? 
I've been Googling like a maniac and cannot find an answer.

Anybody?

CHEERS!

Comment: If you press `Alt+9` do you see a `Changes` window at the bottom?

Comment: I do but how does that solve my problem? It just shows the local changes in the working directory or the entire tree of commits and tags.